# How can I move image data from one table to another?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
include ("connect.php");
$id=@addslashes($_GET['id']);
$image=@mysql_query("select * from tipuranibasti where id = $id");
$image_row=@mysql_fetch_assoc($image);  
$name=@$image_row['name'];
$date=@$image_row['date']; 
$msg=@$image_row['msg'];
$image=addslashes(@file_get_contents($image_row['image']));


if(@mysql_query("insert into puranibasti values('','$name','$date','$msg','$image')"))
{
echo "image has been inserted successfully";
} else
{
echo "problem inserting the image";
}
?>
```

1 im able to move all data to table puranibasti from tipuranibasti except image  can     anyone please help

Comment: Doesn't `insert into puranibasti select '',name,date,msg,image from tipuranibasti where id = $id` work?

Comment: Please use prepared queries with PDO, or at the very least, `mysql_real_escape_string`. `addslashes` is not enough protection against SQL injection.

Comment: Suppressing errors is a horrible practice, please create some error handling, it's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can insert value in a single sql sentence instead select + insert:

```
if(
   @mysql_query("     
      insert into puranibasti  
      select '', name, date, msg, image 
      from tipuranibasti where id = $id"
  ")
```

Comment: i tried this one also but i suffer from the same problem.image field has not been copied from tipuranibasti to puranibasti. other item (id ,name,date,msg are bieng copied but not image) .In table puranibasti field image it store(or look like) as [BLOB - 0B])

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO target (id, name, date, msg, image)
SELECT '', name, date, msg, image FROM source
WHERE source.id = $id
```

This approach prevents you from having to convert sql values to php and then back from php to sql.